# How to fix TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>) in react-native

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication, react-native

I need to store firebase authentication token as a user in react native asyncstorage. here is my code.

```js
loginUser = async (email, pw) => {
        if (this.state.isConnected) {
            if (email != '' && pw != '') {
                try {
                    let user = fb.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pw).catch((err) => {
                        alert('Invalid email or password');
                    });
                    this.storeUser(JSON.stringify(user))
                    console.log(user);
                } catch (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            } 
        } 
    }

    storeUser = async (user) => {
        try {
            await AsyncStorage.setItem('User', JSON.stringify(user)).then(() => {
                console.log("Success user");
            })
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    }
```

but it gives me this error

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
     at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
```

can anyone help me with this?

Comment: just change the JSON.stringify(user) to user in your call to `this.storeUser(JSON.stringify(user));`

Comment: tried it. but not working. still have the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an incorrect usage of the `signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pw)` function call, the [firebase.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth.html#signinwithemailandpassword) function returns a `Promise<UserCredential>` object which will error out when you call `JSON.stringify()` on it.

The returned `UserCredential` object  needs to be retrieved from the Promise by using the `then()` method of the `Promise` class. See below:

```js
try {
    fb.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pw).then(function(userCred) => {
             this.storeUser(userCred);
             console.log(JSON.stringify(userCred)); // so you can see a JSON string in the logs
        }).catch((err) => {
            alert('Invalid email or password');
    });
}
```

Disclaimer: As the entire function is not shown, play with the above

Answer (score 0):

**From Above Code the mistake is converting two times**

> await AsyncStorage.setItem('User', user).then(() => {

```
Updated Code : 

loginUser = async (email, pw) => {
        if (this.state.isConnected) {
            if (email != '' && pw != '') {
                try {
                    let user = fb.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pw).catch((err) => {
                        alert('Invalid email or password');
                    });
                    this.storeUser(JSON.stringify(user))
                    console.log(user);
                } catch (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            } 
        } 
    }

    storeUser = async (user) => {
        try {
            await AsyncStorage.setItem('User', user).then(() => {
                console.log("Success user");
            })
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: tried it. but not working. still have the same error.